# ScrollView not able to scroll horizontally with FlatList

Tags: react-native

Currently I have a FlatList that is holding my images. This Flatlist is inside a ScrollView component where I want the Flatlist images to be able to be scrolled horizontally. But for some reason even after enabling horizontal={true} in my flatlist, my extra images are going to the next row and the scrolling is vertical. [Reference Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eUnz6.png)

Here is my code:

```
const ITEM_WIDTH = Dimensions.get('window').width / 1.2;
const BottomImages: React.FC<FamilyCarouselProps> = ({ family }) => {  

const columns = family.length;

  const [activeItemIndex, setActiveItemIndex] = useState()

return(
  <ScrollView horizontal={true}>
    <FlatList
      numColumns={columns}
      data={family}
      renderItem={({ item }) => {
        return (
          <ListItem
            itemWidth={(ITEM_WIDTH - (10 * columns)) / columns}
            image={item}
            itemIndex={item.id}
            activeItemIndex={activeItemIndex}
            onChangeActiveItemIndex={(index)=>{
              setActiveItemIndex(index)
            }}
          />
        );
      }}
    />
    </ScrollView>
);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should enable the horizontal prop inside your FlatList and not in your ScrollView.

```
const ITEM_WIDTH = Dimensions.get('window').width / 1.2;
const BottomImages: React.FC<FamilyCarouselProps> = ({ family }) => {  

const columns = family.length;

  const [activeItemIndex, setActiveItemIndex] = useState()

return( 
    <FlatList
      horizontal={true}
      numColumns={columns}
      data={family}
      renderItem={({ item }) => {
        return (
          <ListItem
            itemWidth={(ITEM_WIDTH - (10 * columns)) / columns}
            image={item}
            itemIndex={item.id}
            activeItemIndex={activeItemIndex}
            onChangeActiveItemIndex={(index)=>{
              setActiveItemIndex(index)
            }}
          />
        );
      }}
    /> 
);
}
```